# Blazor EditForm OnValidSubmit - what happens after it completes?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

My program works fine, but I want to know what occurs behind the scenes. For an ASP.NET Core 6 Blazor serverside web app, In a razor page I have:

```
<EditForm Model="@Employee" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit"
      OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit">
```

And after my code in HandleValidSubmit executes, I have a new record in the database, I've reset the object that populates the input fields in the form, and everything is rendered with the new empty values.

So what is going on here? Is the page re-rendered new? Or does it just update anything on the page with an @variable? Is anything else going on? Are any events triggered?

Comment: Nothing, there's no magic unless you code it.  The `editcontext` is still linked to whatever object you have it linked to and it's change state hasn't updated.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis But the page clearly re-renders based on changes in the data displayed on the screen???

Comment: The page re-renders because the `OnValidSubmit` callback is a UI event on the main page.  All UI events trigger the `IHandleEvent` registered handler implemented by `ComponentBase`.  This runs the actual event hander, `HandleValidSubmit`, triggers a render event if the handler yields, and then runs a second render event when the handler completes.   What data gets displayed depends on what you've done with the model object in the event handler.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thank you, that explains how it happens. If you post that as an answer, happy to accept it to give you the points. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing, there's no magic unless you code it.

The page re-renders because the `OnValidSubmit` callback is a UI event on the main page. All UI events trigger the `IHandleEvent` registered handler implemented by `ComponentBase`.

This:

1. Runs the actual event hander, `HandleValidSubmit`,
2. Triggers a render event if the handler yields,
3. And runs a second render event when the handler completes.

What data gets displayed depends on what you've done with the model object in the event handler. The `editcontext` is still linked to whatever object you have it linked to and it's change state hasn't updated unless you've changed it in `HandleValidSubmit`.